# Random generation of variable sized test files

Tags: bash, automated-tests

Here is script i am planning to use to generate 500 test files populated with random data.

```
for((counter=1;counter<=500;counter++));
          do
             echo Creating file$counter;
             dd bs=1M count=10 if=/dev/urandom of=file$counter;

               done
```

But what i need the script to do is make those 500 files to be of variable size as in let say between 1M and 10M; ie, file1=1M, file2=10M, file3=9M etc …

any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will generate 500 files each containing between 1 and 10 megabytes of random bytes.

```
#!/bin/bash
max=10    # number of megabytes
for ((counter=1; counter<=500; counter++))
do
    echo Creating file$counter
    dd bs=1M count=$(($RANDOM%max + 1)) if=/dev/urandom of=file$counter
done
```

The second line could instead be:

```
for counter in {1..500}
```

Comment: the random number count=$(($RANDOM%max + 1)), can be achieved without the "+1", what is the requirement of it.

Comment: @OpenFile: Without adding 1 the range of file sizes is 0 to 9 megabytes instead of 1 to 10 (which was one of OP's requirements). All three answers add 1, by the way, for this reason.

Answer (score 3):

```
set MAX=10
for((counter=1;counter<=500;counter++));
do
  echo "Creating file$counter"
  dd bs=$(( ($RANDOM%$MAX)+1  ))M count=10 if=/dev/urandom of=file$counter
done
```

Comment: Many thanks seems i shouldn't need "set" plus don't know why it is not stable i get errors like "Creating file4
dd: invalid number `0M' " sometimes...?

Comment: This would be between 0 and 90 MB in steps of 10 MB instead of 1-10 MB in 1 MB steps.

Comment: fixed by adding +1 in example

Answer (score 1):

Try `$((1+$RANDOM%$MAX))`